# Check overlap in R

Tags: r, overlap

My goal is checking overlap between drugs by each subject. When I compared each row, I left out some rows should be overlap.

```
df <- data.frame(ID= c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2), 
             Drug = c("A","A","A","B","A","B","A","A","A"),
             Start = c(0,529,12.86,35.57,0.29,17.57,18,20,14),
             End=c(5,12,35.57,35.57,2,20.57,18.14,20.57,24))
df1 <- df[order(df$ID, df$Start),]
df1$filter = F



for(k in 2:nrow(df1)){
if(df1$ID[k]==df1$ID[k-1] && df1$Start[k]<=df1$End[k-1] && df1$Drug[k] != 
df1$Drug[k-1]){
df1$filter[k-1]=T
df1$filter[k]=T
 }
}
df1

  ID Drug  Start   End filter
1  1    A   0.00  5.00  FALSE
3  1    A  12.86 35.57   TRUE
4  1    B  35.57 35.57   TRUE
2  1    A 529.00 12.00  FALSE
5  2    A   0.29  2.00  FALSE
9  2    A  14.00 24.00   TRUE
6  2    B  17.57 20.57   TRUE
7  2    A  18.00 18.14   TRUE
8  2    A  20.00 20.57  FALSE <- ** that should be TRUE, it's overlap with Drug B (row 6)
```

There is anyway to fix that loop or use some different approaches? A person can take so many drugs at once

UPDATE DATA

```
rm(list = ls())
ID <- c(rep(1,4), rep(3, 5), rep(4,4),rep(5,5))
Drug <- 
c("A","A","B","A","A","C","D","A","C","A","A","B","B","A","A","B","B","C")
Begin<- c(0,2.5,3,4,7,8,7,25,25,10,15,1,2,1,6,10,11,13)
End <- c(1.5,3.5,3,6,12,8,11,29,35, 12,19,1,28,5,20,30,20,25)
Dose <- c(1:18)
df <- data.frame(ID,Drug, Begin, End,Dose)
df1 <- df[order(df$ID, df$End),]
```

I think I got filter variable, but I have problem to get pair of drug overlap, here is the output of pair variable I want

```
df1 <- df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(max = (cummax(End)))
df1$filter = F


for(k in 2:nrow(df1)){
  if(df1$ID[k]==df1$ID[k-1] && df1$Begin[k]<=df1$max[k-1] && df1$Drug[k] != 
df1$Drug[k-1]){
    df1$filter[k-1]=T
    df1$filter[k]=T
  }
}

df2 <- subset(df1, df1$filter == T)
        ID   Drug Begin   End  Dose   max filter  pair
 <dbl> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>  <lgl>
 1     1      B   3.0   3.0     3   3.0   TRUE    (B,A)
 2     1      A   2.5   3.5     2   3.5   TRUE    (B,A)
 3     3      C   8.0   8.0     6   8.0   TRUE    (C,D,A)
 4     3      D   7.0  11.0     7  11.0   TRUE    (C,D,A)
 5     3      A   7.0  12.0     5  12.0   TRUE    (C,D,A)
 6     3      A  25.0  29.0     8  29.0   TRUE    (A,C)
 7     3      C  25.0  35.0     9  35.0   TRUE    (A,C)
 8     4      A  15.0  19.0    11  19.0   TRUE    (A,B)
 9     4      B   2.0  28.0    13  28.0   TRUE    (A,B)
10     5      A   6.0  20.0    15  20.0   TRUE    (A,B,C)
11     5      B  11.0  20.0    17  20.0   TRUE    (A,B,C)
12     5      C  13.0  25.0    18  25.0   TRUE    (A,B,C)
13     5      B  10.0  30.0    16  30.0   TRUE    (A,B,C)
```

Comment: Why in row 4 `Start` is larger than `End`?

Comment: Sorry it's typo, but now I am getting another trouble, I need to get which pair   is overlap, only TRUE and FALSE, it helps only get subset of TRUE, then need to set which pairs overlap

Comment: Is your question: how do I create a logical (TRUE/FALSE) variable, indicating overlap in intervals (difference between begin and end), by drug (e.g. A) and within persons (ID)?

Comment: @Richard Yes, I want 2 variables, logical (TRUE/FALSE) and overlap in intervals (difference between begin and end), by drug (e.g. A) and within persons (ID), so later on I can find the max of Dose they take a day. I tried `foverlaps` in `data.table`, it gives me the pair of the drug, but sometimes one person exposed 3 drugs differently and 3 of them have interval overlaps